# TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create anchor link scroll and also tool tip display with bootstrap

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
       $('#header').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
       $('#header').removeClass('fixed').fadeOut("slow", 100);
     }
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
});


$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('a.scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

but i am getting this error in the console 
TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function

[image]
demo link
http://itracktraining.com/bb2/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) documentation, the first argument is supposed to be the duration of the animation and the second argument should be a callback. These durations can either be in milliseconds (as you have put in your second argument), or a string which alias as timeframes.

Basically, you need to change your `fadeOut` code in one of the following ways:

```
$('#header').removeClass('fixed').fadeOut("slow");

// OR

$('#header').removeClass('fixed').fadeOut(100);
```

You are also using `easeInOutExpo` for the easing. JQuery does not come bundled with this easing. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing) page which says:

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI suite.

To use that easing, you will need to make sure you include [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) as an external library on the page.

You will also need jQuery UI for the use of the `tooltip` method.

Comment: @DivyaSharma please see my updated answer, which includes an explanation on the use of `fadeOut`.